# Check if user turned off mobile data/wifi connection and update it to firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Hy. I am building a chat application in flutter and I want to show users last seen, offline and online status, using firebase as the backend. I complete all these active status things..like storing offline online and typing status. but the problem is if the user turns off the data while using the app the user active status is showing as online . Because he was using the app. So how can I change that status to offline, if the user turns off the internet connection from mobile .

Comment: Well, you obviously can't send any updates anymore, when the user turned of any data connection. You can add a ping, that connects to the backend ever xy seconds and updates the "last seen" timestamp. When you display your userlist you can then check if "last seen" is older than that xy seconds. If no, display the user as online, else display it as offline ...

Comment: Also it will be costly if you are using firebase. because if you ping server at every xyz seconds its increase read write request